# Android Studio AdMob Integration With Google Play Services

Tags: android, android-studio, admob, google-play-services

I am trying to add admob features to my application. I have done everything but I am missing some key points.

Here is my graddle:

```
apply plugin: 'android'

android {
compileSdkVersion 19
buildToolsVersion '19.0.1'

defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 13
    targetSdkVersion 19
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        runProguard false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-    rules.txt'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:+'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:+'
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar', '*.aar'])
}
```

This is the XML Layout part for ads view

```
`<com.google.ads.AdView
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
    android:id="@+id/adView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-8644867804576560/1489221139"
    ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
    ads:testDevices="*******50664**2"
    ads:loadAdOnCreate="true"/>`
```

These meta tags and necessary permissions are added to Manifest.xml

```
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version"/>

<activity android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"/>
```

Finally this is the logcat at the crash moment.

```
02-16 12:50:31.941    8898-8898/com.exampl.deneme E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.exampl.deneme/com.exampl.deneme.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #16: Error inflating class com.google.ads.AdView
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2295)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2349)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:159)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1316)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5419)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1187)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1003)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #16: Error inflating class com.google.ads.AdView
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:713)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:761)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:498)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:398)
        at com.exampl.deneme.MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment.onCreateView(MainActivity.java:60)
        at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1500)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:927)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1104)
        at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1467)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:570)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1188)
        at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:5382)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2266)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2349)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:159)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1316)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5419)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1187)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1003)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.ads.AdView" on path: /data/app/com.exampl.deneme-1.apk
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:64)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:565)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:702)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:761)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:498)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:398)
        at     com.exampl.deneme.MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment.onCreateView(MainActivity.java:60)
        at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1500)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:927)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1104)
        at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1467)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:570)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1188)
        at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:5382)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2266)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2349)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:159)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1316)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5419)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1187)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1003)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

By the way code compiles with no error, this happens at run time.  I don't want to use [this](https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/#android) version as it is going to be deprecated. Trying to get [this](https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/#play) version work.

I believe I am very close to the solution but couldn't achieve to get there. It is so nonsense at compile time it recognizes everything when it comes to run it directly crashes with the above errors.

What may it be that I am missing?

Comment: silly question but have you tried to clean(Build> Clean Project) and Rebuild it ?

Comment: Tried but still no sound.

Comment: I have used the approach stated [here][1] and strangely it worked well. 


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19956048/should-we-prefer-admob-in-google-play-services-compared-to-old-admob-sdk/21281694#21281694

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change `com.google.ads.AdView` into `com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView`.

You are using the Google Play Service, not Admob SDK

Be happy :).