# Difference between two similar Goodle Unity Ads plugins

Tags: unity-game-engine, google-play-services, ads

Tere is a two plugins for Unity from Google for having Ads in your app.

First, based on firebase and provided via google play services:

https://github.com/googleads/googleads-mobile-unity

Second one, also well-updated, used by some people plugin for similar purposes as as well as first plugin.

https://github.com/unity-plugins/Unity-Admob

I am new in Ads in Unity3d, and I want to make it clear, what is the difference between them ?

I think someone can give a proper answer.

Comment: I set some feedback for you @Vladislav Hromyh

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this can help.

[Should we prefer AdMob in Google Play services compared to "old" AdMob SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19956048/should-we-prefer-admob-in-google-play-services-compared-to-old-admob-sdk)

But I think to read more their docs and choose, is best solution to choose.

Comment: It did not help me to undestand the diffs. Could you explain me this if you have an understanding of question ?

Answer (score 0):

I checked https://github.com/unity-plugins/Unity-Admob project and as you may check also in the doc there is no way for you to set the applicationID.

Google Ads cannot play without that ID. Also that plugin would try to take storage and WiFi access and as we know this is not needed for Admob.

I suggest you better use https://github.com/googleads/googleads-mobile-unity which is a official plugin at the moment.